# How can I set my Caps Lock key to toggle Fullscreen mode in Xmonad?

Tags: fullscreen, xmonad, capslock

I'm using xmonad with the following layouts:

```
globalLayout = avoidStruts (tiled ||| Mirror tiled ||| Full ||| threeColMid ||| combine) ||| Full
```

and I have set my mod + space key to switch between the layouts by:

```
, ((modm, xK_space ), sendMessage NextLayout)
```

Now I want to bind my CapsLock key to toggle the Full mode. How can I do that? (Maybe with setLayout?)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

see [XMonad.Layout.MultiToggle](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/xmonad-contrib/0.8/doc/html/XMonad-Layout-MultiToggle.html)

You need two imports:

```
import XMonad.Layout.MultiToggle
import XMonad.Layout.MultiToggle.Instances
```

key binding:

```
((modm, xK_Caps_Lock), sendMessage $ Toggle FULL)
```

layout:

```
layout
  = smartBorders
  $ mkToggle (NOBORDERS ?? FULL ?? EOT)
  $ tiled ||| Mirror tiled ||| etc...
```

Enjoy.

Comment: This is almost what I was looking for but it doesn't work with floating windows.

Comment: @ideasman42 good point. Did you find a way to overcome that limitation?

Comment: Yes, my dotfile is here: https://bitbucket.org/ideasman42/dotfiles/src/master/.xmonad/xmonad.hs

Answer (score 0):

This also works to launch an app in full screen:

```
, ((modMask .|. shiftMask, xK_l), sendMessage $ JumpToLayout "Full"
```